# Update impossible. Blocks at renewing MySQL pack. Cant remove MySQL

Tags: command-line, updates

I try to update MySQL but the update gets stuck at:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I do the `sudo dpkg` thing and it stops at:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
mysql stop/waiting
```

So I must get rid of MySQL so I can update, but I must first update in order to be able to remove MySQL.

Can somebody help, please?

Comment: Take a look into the mysql-logs - you might find a hint as to why the service cannot start (starting a service is part of the installation process on Ubuntu).